# Unable to format the HTML output

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping

I have python code that returns an HTML page. Within that page, there is a line "2092 Pittman Road" which is the parcel address. My code is below:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open("https://www.matsugov.us/myproperty")
for form in br.forms():
    if form.attrs.get('name') == 'frmSearch':
    br.form = form
    break
br.form['ddlType']=["taxid"]
br['txtParm']="218N02W27C003"
req=br.submit().read()
print req
```

req gives me the o/p in HTML format. You can run this code as is to see the o/p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code, this will work for you:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import mechanize
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    response = br.open("https://www.matsugov.us/myproperty")
    for form in br.forms():
         if form.attrs.get('name') == 'frmSearch':
         br.form = form
         break
    br.form['ddlType']=["taxid"]
    br['txtParm']="218N02W27C003"
    req=br.submit().read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('td', {'class': 'Grid_5'})
    for row in table:
         print row
```

Answer (score 0):

Feed your HTML to [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), and then navigate or format it as you wish.